# Search for a string from a text file in java script

Tags: javascript, mobile, tizen

I am creating a Dictionary app for mobile using Java Script. I have stored Dictionary source in a separate file. My doubt is how to access that file and search for particular string using Java Script.

```
function dic() {
    var word = document.getElementById("wo").value;
    var dictionary = new Array("Java","Python","Swift","HTML","PHP");
    var flag = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
        if(dictionary[i] == word) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Element Found";
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0)
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Element Not Found";  

}
```

This script checks for the word in array. I want to replace the array words to a text file. Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to **access** the file using server-side code like PHP. Once it's in the document, you can do what you like with it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use PHP. because it's for mobile.

Comment: PHP still works for mobile. There is almost no speed loss (depending on your code), and because it's executed on the server, the platform doesn't need to have it installed.

Comment: It's Tizen app, I already tried PHP in it. It's not executing the code. There is no other way, i have to get code for Java Script only.

Comment: In that case, you might want to look at jQuery's `ajax` functions to get the file into your document. As I said, once it's there you can search through it as normal.

Answer (score 4):

To access the file, use jQuery's `.get()` function. This can also be done with `XMLHttpRequests` in pure JS but jQuery will handle cross-browser compatibilty for you.

To get the file:

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/path/to/file.txt",function(returnedData) {
    $("#element").text(returnedData);
},"text/plain");
```

This will load the contents of http://www.example.com/path/to/file.txt into the `div` with ID `element`. Assuming each dictionary word is on a new line, you can then separate them into an array with the following:

```
var text = $("#element").text();
var words = text.split("\n");
var dictionary = new Array();
for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
    dictionary[i] = words[i];
}
```

Now you have the dictionary words in your array and can search for them with your existing code (with a couple of corrections):

```
function dic() {
    var word = document.getElementById("wo").value;
    // var dictionary = new Array("Java","Python","Swift","HTML","PHP");
    // This line is unnecessary; use the dictionary var already created.
    var flag = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
        if(dictionary[i] == word) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Element Found";
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        if(i == dictionary.length - 1) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Element Not Found"; 
        }
    }
}
```

That should leave you with the right answer.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Part of the code in my second code sample is unnecessary and only there for clarity; you can in fact just state that `var dictionary = text.split("\n");`, which will yield the same result.