# I want to Find a string in java script

Tags: javascript

I want to search for a string in all .txt files in one folder and return the file namw. The folder can have sub folders and the string I Want to search should be passed as parameter.
 For ex I want all the file name and locations which have the string 0754665477

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use Java instead of JavaScript. Didn't you?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. :v

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231617/search-for-a-string-from-a-text-file-in-java-script

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan may be he is using node.js

Comment: You cannot read dics content by JavaScript, JavaScript is browser only, unless you are using some kind of nodeJS, but that will work as a Backend app. Cookies are the only exeption to this rule. Or you could doenload file content via Ajax... but that has little sence.

Comment: @AshishNegi, no matter what the case is. This question is not constructive and too low on information about the scenario too. I suggest he/she edit the post.

Comment: @Beri that's not true. There's stuff like [the File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System). And then there's things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1087257/238310). I still imagine he's using Java or node.js though.

Comment: Damn it, I must be out of date then:) Thanks for the news:)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Totally agree with you on that.

Comment: @Vaish Take your time to read about how to ask questions on stackoverflow.. and it would be great if you can show what you have done till now.. Or keep doing this for future questions..

Answer (score 0):

[How to read text file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript)

here you can see how to read files with javascript.

Once you you have the text in a string variable, apply the .search method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp